# Complementing ith bit

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, x86-16

Assuming AX contains a number between 0 and 15. Now the "AXth" bit in BX has to be complemented.
For example, AX contains the value `6` then the 6th bit in BX should be complemented.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xor` operation is neatly fitted for that.

(All code in Intel syntax.)

```
mov cl, al
```

Moves the bit's index to `cl`; the 8086 supports either `shl` by one bit or by `cl` bits.

```
mov ax, 01h
```

Sets first bit of `ax` while clearing all other bits.

```
shl ax, cl
```

Shift the set bit to the left; sets the `cl`th bit in `ax` (as in your example, the 6th bit).

```
xor bx, ax
```

Complements (inverts) the corresponding bit in `bx`. `xor` works because

```
0 xor 0 = 0
1 xor 0 = 1
0 xor 1 = 1
1 xor 1 = 0
```

Note that for later processors of the x86 processor line there are shorter variants in order to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say anything about wanting to support hardware from 30 years ago, so I'll assume a modern x86, even if you're programming it in 16bit mode for some strange reason.

```
btc  bx, ax    # bt / bts / btr / btc were new with 80386
```

It stores the original value of `bx & (1<<ax)` into the carry flag, hence the mnemonic: Bit Test and Complement.

This instruction is slow with a memory operand, but single-cycle latency and 2-per-clock throughput in the `btc reg, reg` and `btc reg, imm8` forms. (Intel Sandybridge family).

The memory-operand forms are like the `bt` insn, with crazy CISC semantics that treat memory as a bit-string starting at the given address.  So instead of just testing with the 8 / 16 / 32bit value at the given address, a high bit-position will actually affect a bit in a different byte.  To handle this wacky requirement, recent Intel designs decode `bt/btc mem, r` to 10 uops from microcode, with a throughput of one per 5 clocks.  `bt/r/s/c  m,i`  decodes to 3 uops (or 2, for `bt` that only reads), so it's not terrible for testing a known position in a bitfield.  It's faster to load an then `bt` the register in 2 steps if the bit position is variable.