# XORing a bit in x86 -- using xor vs btc

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, xor

I'm (still) making my way through some of the [bit hacks](https://catonmat.net/low-level-bit-hacks), and doing it all in assembly, for example from a previous question, [Check if a number is even](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64112337/check-if-a-number-is-even).

Here is what I have for toggling a bit:

```
toggle_bit:
    # NUM XOR (1 <<POS), pos is 1-indexed
    # Note: 
    #  NUM xor 0 = NUM
    #  NUM xor 1 = not(NUM), i.e., flip all bits
    mov $1, %eax        # the bit to shift (pos-1)
    lea -1(%esi), %ecx  # shift amount -- pos-1
    shl %cl, %rax       # now we have the 1 at the correct bit position
    xor %rdi, %rax
    ret
```

And called as:

```
mov $0b101, %edi # (5)
mov $2, %esi     # (toggle 2nd bit)
call toggle_bit  # return 0b111 (7)
```

Is this  the suggested way to toggle a bit? Or should I be using the [`btc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/btc) instruction?

---

**Update**: here is my improved function using `btc`:

```
toggle_bit:
    mov %rdi, %rax  # move the num into the return register
    dec %sil        # so pos it's one-indexed
    btc %rsi, %rax
    ret
```

It's one instruction shorter than the first way -- is one way 'better' than the other. If so, why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complementing ith bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680998/complementing-ith-bit) (which mentions that `btc` is good if both operands are registers)

Comment: [gcc likes btc](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3TWcae).

Comment: @harold I added an update since I asked. Is one way preferred over the other then?

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks, yea I just ran it through Compiler Explorer and posted an update after getting a helper from that.

Comment: Apart from using `btc`, the most obvious improvement would be to stop using this weird 1-indexed bit position crap that forces you to `dec` the input.  shift and bit-scan instructions (like `bsf` and `bsr`) all use 0-indexed bit position: the first bit is bit #0.  And of course it never makes sense to wrap this in a function call, just inline a `btc` instruction, or if the bit-position is a known constant, an xor-immediate.